# Rails 3: Multiple Database Connection Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one rails app and two different databases.

**Use Case:**

> If I browse http://mydomain.com, then it point to one rails app
>
> If I browse http://mydomain.com/project1, then it point to same rails
>   app with different database let's say project1DB
>
> If I browse http://mydomain.com/project2, then it point to same rails
>   app with different database let's say project2DB
>
> Both databases are identical in terms of tables and schema

I can achieve this by using `establish_connection "project1DB"` into model but i don't want to modify my model.

I tried following way into `application controller` but it didn't work sometimes

```
before_filter :dbconnect

def dbconnect
      if session[:product] == "project1"
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 'project1_' + Rails.env  
      end

      if session[:product] == "project2"
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 'project2_' + Rails.env  
      end
end
```

Comment: Are there two DB's here or three (mydomain.com, mydomain.com/project1, mydomain.com/project2)?  Basically I'm wondering if there is a set of "core" tables (accounts/users/etc) that are contained in a central DB and which support branching out into the project DBs.

Comment: @AndyV yes there are three database and all are idential